# HP ProLiant DL380 G6 server error code: 347 of array controller

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have got a brand new hp ProLiant DL380 G6 server with embedded smart array P410i controller, I got 146 GB SAS drives and wanted to change them with 300 GB SAS drives before installation. Now, we replace the drives and begin the configuration with the hp DVD and begin; when we reach the point that we want to save the configurations, an error message appears:

"The operation has failed with an unknown error, please restart the application and attempt the operation again"

When using Rescan System, this error message appears:

```
     "Status Alerts -
      Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot

      Warning Status Message

      Code   Description
      347    The cache for Smart Array P410i Embedded Slot is not configured"
```

### I return back to the 146 GB SAS drives and the message just keeps appearing again.

This server is brand new never used before -was stored on the client office- and I check and found that this model of servers comes with non battery Smart Array controller.
Any help please.

Comment: @wwhite This server is brand new never used before -was stored on the client office- and I check and found that this model of servers comes with non battery Smart Array controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... The HP ProLiant DL380 G6 is not a new server model. It's a few years old. So given that, where did the server come from? If it's been used previously, you may have some additional work to clear its configurations.

Usually, the error you received is a result of not having *any* cache module or battery on the embedded Smart Array RAID controller.

As far as the disks, are *sure* that they are SATA and not SAS drives?

Also, is your system firmware up-to-date? Make sure to obtain the Firmware Update DVD or [**HP Service Pack for ProLiant**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/).

Comment: I have found you should use both. Boot server from Firmware Update DVD. Then run PSP from the windows desktop. You can use the DVD for both but it takes longer to do it that way in my experience.

Comment: I'm downloading the firmware now, will check after installation and feed you back

Comment: I checked the Firmware and found it the last version, still I can not configure the smart array. Should I replace it or What?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late answer, we are giving up along time ago & just replaced the Smart Array P410i controller which works fine.

thanks for all your helpful support